# How can you call the variable name instead of its value?

Tags: javascript, variables

So, say I have the code

```
let foo1 = 1,
foo2 = 2,
foo3 = 3,
foo4 = 4,
bar = [];
```

Is it possible to write a function that will take the name of a variable, and then allow me to push that to bar, or would the variable's value always get called instead of the name? If it *is* always the value getting called, is there a way to get the name of a reference rather than the reference value in a different way?

Comment: You could only do such a thing with global variables. If these foo variables are scoped then it will not be possible, unless you use `eval` which is not recommended.

Comment: Please explain the context. Are these global variables, or are they local to a block scope?

Comment: That said, popular frameworks such as angular rely heavily on `eval` so maybe you should just have at it.

Comment: @trincot global variables

Comment: What you are asking implies that you will treat your code as a string or another structure. It will be better if you explain what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an object and use the properties as name.

```js
var object = {
        foo1: 1,
        foo2: 2,
        foo3: 3,
        foo4: 4,
        foo5: 5,
    },
    key = 'foo1',
    bar = [];

bar.push(object[key]);

console.log(bar)
```